# Buffer.byteLength() is bugged

Tags: node.js

node version is 0.6.17.

I was trying to get the number of bytes of a character ([SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571814/how-to-count-the-number-of-bytes-of-a-character)) but now I'm testing how to get the REAL number of bytes. The REAL number means that if the char has a value greater than 127 it has to be encoded with a leading extra byte ([UTF8 wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)).

Please see:

```
console.log (Buffer.byteLength ("a", "utf8"));  //bytes: 1, UNICODE hex: 0x61 (1), REAL hex: 0x61 (1)
console.log (Buffer.byteLength ("¡", "utf8"));  //bytes: 2, UNICODE hex: 0xA1 (1), REAL hex: 0xC2A1 (2)
console.log (Buffer.byteLength ("↑", "utf8"));  //bytes: 3, UNICODE hex: 0x2191 (2), REAL hex: 0xE28691 (3)
console.log (Buffer.byteLength ("", "utf8")); //bytes: 3, UNICODE hex: 0x24065 (3), REAL hex: 0xF0A481A5 (4)
```

Here we have 2 possibilities:

1. `Buffer.byteLength()` returns the UNICODE number of bytes. Example: Unicode for `¡` is 0xA1 (1 byte). If this is true, then the function is bugged because it returns 2 (real length is 2).
2. `Buffer.bytelength()` returns the REAL number of bytes. Example: Real hex value for  is 0xF0A481A5 (4 bytes). If this is true, then the function is bugged because it returns 3 (unicode length is 3).

What do you think? Is the function bugged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3262#issuecomment-5677385

node.js version 6 only supports [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane) character set (0x0000 - 0xFFFF). Version 7 and above supports characters greater than 0xFFFF (not tested).

The function returns the REAL length, so examples 1, 2, 3 are correct and 4 is incorrect.